# Как поменять содержимое местами в друпале

Tags: drupal

Здравствуйте, конечно понимаю что такие вопросы задают дети, вообщем поймите меня, и так подключил карусель к статьям в друпале, только вот расположился не там где хотелось бы поменять местами, чтоб карусель был после текста а не до текста, все "ВЕСы" уже перепробовал изменить но без вариантов. Скиньте пару слов)

[image]

Comment: в меню редактирование типа материала, если это у вас кастомный материал - можно мышкой перетащить поля, изменив таким образом порядок

Comment: в меню редактирование типа материала, не нашел такого чтобы можно было мышкой перетаскивать. Да конечно кустомный. Может есть еще варианты к-й вы знаете?

Answer (score 1):

В управление отображением /admin/structure/types/manage/(машинное имя контент-типа)/display -> "По умолчанию" переместить поле с картинками ниже боди.
Или можно так - Создаёте node--CONTENT_TYPE.tpl.php И выводите поле "imade" отдельно от массива. Пример: <div class="content">

```
<?php
      hide($content['comments']);
      hide($content['field_image']); // Машинное имя поля
      print render($content);
    ?>
```

</div>
<div class="gallery">`<?php print render($content['field_image']); ?>`</div>  
C помощью Devel или print_r можете посмотреть, что содержит массив $content.